# Word 2010 - automatic updating table in footnotes

Tags: microsoft-word, documents

I would like to insert a table footer in my policy manual which shows the for example the "Version" (draft 1, draft 2, final etc) "Date of Update", "Updated by".  Is there any way of Word 2010 automatically updating the data so that versions don't get mixed up?

Comment: this looks compelling: http://autohistory.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

@Alice,

@Chris mentions the use of a third-party software. Even though there is always an option to install third-party software that will benefit the end-user, this question seems to be directed towards increasing end-user knowledge of the software, and NOT learning about more software.

Document version naming (V1, V2, V3, etc...) may be difficult, as many programs only see "versions" as "deltas" in information (if info is added or deleted, that's the "newer" version).

Knowing this, let's examine features within Word 2010 that will help with your concern:

As previously stipulated, the closest thing a computer understands for version is date of creation/date of update.

Follow these steps to open the "Field" window in Word 2010:

1) Open the header/footer of your document. Do this by double-clicking near the top of the page. This opens the "Header and Footer Tools" in the Word 2010 Ribbon at the top of the screen (the tab colour should be green by default).

2) In the "Insert" section of the "Header and Footer Tools", click on "Quick Parts." A menu should open up. If "Field..." is available, click it.

3) Under the "Categories" section, isolate commands by selecting "Document Information."

4) If "LastSavedBy" is selected, Word 2010 should display the *name* of the user that last saved the document. However, please be aware that the name of the user may not match the person's actual name (if an individual is using a computer at an institution, "Corp XYZ" may be the user).

5) Press "OK" and see what happens. A field should be inserted. This field will be "greyed out," and your name (entered when you set-up Word 2010) will be displayed.

Other options:

If "Date and Time" is selected from the "Categories" field in the "Field" window, you see the following options:

- CreateDate
- Date
- EditTime
- PrintDate
- SaveDate
- Time

These are all self-explanatory when examining their titles. However, the description field is available at the bottom by the button "Field Codes."

Hope that helps!

O_P